# Lost ability to Tab through TextFields with Components

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have 8 TextFields placed on the stage. I have a tab order setup and was able to get to the next field by pressing Tab. After adding 2 components (UIScollBar and Button) to the stage, I have somehow lost this ability. How can I get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check for the [FocusManager class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00002510.html) in flash documentation. That'll guide you through how to set tab-order on components.

Are all these elements (8 textfields, two components) loose on the stage? or are they  grouped within movieclips?